# Deseralize XML to object

Tags: c#

Here is a response from a HTTP post

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<xdpwebservice><responses><response><valid>OK</valid><consignmentno>ZDBXXX171908</consignmentno><label>https://xdp.sysx.co.uk/label/view/8iu7ewK3/108811141</label><references>0000000510</references><date>2023-06-21</date><time>11:44:21</time></response></responses></xdpwebservice>\n"
```

I am trying to deseralize to an object.

My object

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]
public class XDPResponse
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "valid")]
    public string Valid { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "consignmentno")]
    public string Consignmentno { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "references")]
    public int References { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "time")]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "responses")]
public class Responses
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "response")]
    public XDPResponse Response { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "xdpwebservice")]
public class Xdpwebservice
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "responses")]
    public Responses Responses { get; set; }
}
```

}

Deseralize object

```
                      var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XDPResponse));
                    XDPResponse result;

                    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(response))
                    {
                        result = (XDPResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    }
```

I get error: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

I guess the string response may need to be cleaned up.

Comment: *"Deseralize HTML to object"* - should we edit the title to "Deserialize XML to Object?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root type should be `Xdpwebservice`

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xdpwebservice));
```

BTW given the name 'responses', you'd better declare an array in the definition, though there's only one element in this example.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "responses")]
public class Responses
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "response")]
    public XDPResponse[] Response { get; set; }
}
```